# After upgrade to APEX 19.1, setSelection no longer works

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

After upgrading APEX to 19.1, some javaScript stopped working.

```
var my_grid$=apex.region("static_id").widget();
mygrid$.interactiveGrid("getViews", my_grid$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentViewId")).setSelection($());
```

starting giving me errors as it no longer recognizes setSelection as a function. So I changed it to:

```
var my_grid$=apex.region("static_id").widget();
my_grid$.interactiveGrid("getViews",
    my_grid$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentViewId")).setSelectedRecords($(), false, false);
```

So now I no longer get any errors but it still doe snot give me the desired result - de-selects the first row of the interactive grid

Comment: You can read about the JavaScript APIs here: apex.oracle.com/jsapi. Here's the doc for setSelectedRecords: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#setSelectedRecords Note that your first parameter is selecting nothing and the doc says: "If this is an empty array then the selection is cleared." That's probably the behavior you're observing. Which records are you trying to select?

Comment: Thank you, I have read the documentation already. that's the problem - the selection is not cleared. By default the first row is checked and I am attempting to clear it

Comment: I see what you want... I ran your code and it worked fine for me. Your issue is probably in the timing/location of your code. How are you executing it?

Comment: I am executing it from page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Attributes of the region. Under Advanced, put the following code in the JavaScript Initialization Code field:

```
function(options) {
  options.initialSelection = false;

  return options;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to not automatically select the first row in an interactive grid, this is now a declarative option.

Go to the region Attributes and set **Select First Row** to No.

[image]